# Replacement for org.springframework.data.authentication package

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I see this org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials were removed in 2.1.2 version.
But what is its replacement?

i.e. I have a constructor that uses an UserCredentials object to initialise.
What to replace it with?

Comment: I am still working on it. Will approve once it works

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/api/deprecated-list.html)

> since 2.1 without replacement as it was meant for internal use only anyway

As mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-3.authentication), use `MongoCredential` instead `UserCredential`

```
builder
        .credential(MongoCredential.createCredential("name", "db", "pwd".toCharArray()))
        .applyToClusterSettings(settings  -> {
            settings.hosts(singletonList(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017)));
        });
```